# How to convert it into es6 arrow functions? in Vanilla JS

Tags: javascript

Hi i want to convert this code to es6 arrow functions here is the sample code. but i'm getting an error like this:

[image]

```js
let pets = [
  {name: "Meowsalot", species: 'cat', age: 2},
  {name: "Barksalot", species: 'dog', age: 4},
  {name: "Purrsloud", species: 'cat', age: 10}
]

pets.push({
  name: 'Puppster', species: 'dog', age: 1
})

let ourTest = pets.map(nameOnly)

function nameOnly(x) {
  return x.name
}

let dogs = pets.filter(onlyDogs)

function onlyDogs(x) {
  return x.species == 'dog'
}

function onlyBabies(x) {
  return x.age < 3
}

let babyDogNames = pets.filter(onlyDogs).filter(onlyBabies).map(nameOnly)

// here is my es6 version 
let ourTest = pets.map(nameOnly => nameOnly.name);
let dogs = pets.filter(onlyDogs => onlyDogs.species == "dog");

(onlyBabies) => onlyBabies.age < 3
let babyDogNames = pets.filter(onlyDogs).filter(onlyBabies).map(nameOnly);
console.log(babyDogNames);
```

Comment: Post code not pictures of code.

Comment: Hi i change it to actual code sorry about that

Comment: onlyDogs is not defined , but without the es6 version i created it works fine.

Comment: I removed error picture by accident while removing other pictures... Added it back now. @Bergi

Comment: If you don't need to preserve what `this` refers to in the _declaration_ context, you _do not need arrow functions_ and rewriting `function blah(args) { ... }` to an arrow function is entirely meaningless. The code you're showing wants to be a `class Animal` with a constructor that takes a name and a type, or even three classes (`Animal`, `Cat extends Animal`, and `Dog extends Animal`). It does _not_ want to stay loose functions that use arrow notation.

Comment: @raffy Well in the ES6 version you didn't declare a variable `onlyDogs`

Comment: i see, interesting.. i'm trying find to shorten the code . maybe i'll stick with old syntax in this context. @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans thanks.

Comment: I can highly recommend reading through https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions in full to understand when and why you'd use arrow functions. The computer doesn't care about "looks", and well written code looks just as pretty with `function name(args) { /* body */ }` as it does with arrow functions, so really the only time to use arrow functions is if you _need_ arrow functions because you lose the correct `this` reference in the function body if you don't.

Comment: Thanks Mike. yep the' this' keyword is confusing me. i think you're right reading the docs and understand it well is the key here. :) i'm new in JavaScript i'm trying to mess the code so i can practice but if i got stuck need to ask for experience dev here is the best idea :) cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are passing a not declared arrow function in the line `let babyDogNames = pets.filter(onlyDogs).filter(onlyBabies).map(nameOnly);`. You should pass either anonymous arrow functions

```
let babyDogNames = pets.filter(pet => pet.species == 'dog') // filter only dogs
    .filter(pet => pet.age < 3)          // filter only babies
    .map(pet => pet.name);               // get names
```

or declare all arrow functions as variables and then pass them:

```
const onlyDogs = pet => pet.species == 'dog';
const onlyBabies = pet => pet.age < 3;
const onlyNames = pet => pet.name;

let babyDogNames = pets.filter(onlyDogs).filter(onlyBabies).map(onlyNames);
```

Comment: Gordon from Blumberg, Thanks for this answer.. both answers are working, it make sense now to me Thank you guys for answering this question. i get the idea now. Happy Coding everyone :)